# Get list of all followers from twitter using Fabric

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, twitter-fabric

Getting the list of followers from twitter sdk using fabric but not able to get more than 20. And another limitation is need to get the all followers first and then upload to api. I am using code below to get the followers list. Please guide wha changes need to make in existing code or need to shift to some new way.

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
        if (granted) {
             //[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
                NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                            // Check if the users has setup at least one Twitter account
                            if (accounts.count > 0)
                            {
                                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];
                                // Creating a request to get the info about a user on Twitter

                                SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:twitterAccount.username forKey:@"screen_name"]];
                                [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
                                // Making the request

                                [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                        // Check if we reached the reate limit

                                        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                                            NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        if (error) {
                                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        // Check if there is some response data

                                        if (responseData) {

                                            NSError *error = nil;
                                            NSArray *TWData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
                                            // Filter the preferred data
                                            NSArray *arrFollowList = [TWData valueForKey:@"users"];

                                            // Filter the preferred data

                                            NSMutableArray *arrFollowersList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

                                            for(int i =0; i<[arrFollowList count]; i++)
                                            {

                                                NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

                                                [dict setObject:[[arrFollowList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"FriendName"];
                                                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Email"];
                                                [dict setObject:strType forKey:@"FriendType"];
                                                [dict setObject:[[arrFollowList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"UserAccountId"];
                                                //[dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"UserAccountId"];
                                                [dict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Team_Id"];
                                                [dict setObject:[[arrFollowList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"profile_image_url"] forKey:@"ProfileImage"];

                                                [arrFollowersList addObject:dict];

                                            }

                                            NSString *teamId = @"1";
                                            NSDictionary *objDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                     teamId, @"Team_Id",
                                                                     arrFollowersList, @"userFriendList",
                                                                     nil];

                                            NSLog(@"dict %@",objDict);

                                            [iOSRequest postData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", kFriendListUpdateUrl] :objDict :^(NSDictionary *response_success)
                                             {
                                                 NSLog(@"response_success:%@", response_success);

                                                 if([[response_success valueForKey:@"message"] isEqualToString:@"Success"])
                                                 {
                                                     NSMutableDictionary *dictSquads = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                                                     [dictSquads setObject:[standardDefaults valueForKey:@"UserId"] forKey:@"User_Id"];
                                                     [dictSquads setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Team_Id"];
                                                     [dictSquads setObject:strType forKey:@"FriendType"];


                                                 }
                                             }
                                                                :^(NSError *response_error)
                                             {


                                             }];

                                        }
                                    });
                                }];
                            }
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"No access granted");
                            [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
                        }
                    }];
```